# PHP Include Nav-bar For Every Page Techniques?

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to clean up my code in my php web pages by including files to consolidate each page's code's like so:

File: head.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> *Dynamic Page Title* </title>
<meta name"description" "Dynamic Description">
<link href="#">
</head>
```

File: footer.php

```
<footer>
   <ul>
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Page 1</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Page 2</li></a>
   </ul>
</footer>
<script src="#">
</body>
</html>
```

File: navbar.php

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index">Home</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

File: index.php

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
<?php include('nav-bar.php'); ?>
<body>
Index Page, Home has an active class
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

File: Page-1.php

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
<?php include('nav-bar.php'); ?>
<body>
Index Page, Page 1 in nav-bar has an active class
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

You guys get the main idea. I would like tips on how to add active classes in different pages in the nav-bar, and how to add different titles and meta tags to each page.

Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define variables in your files:

`index.php`:

```
<?php $title = 'Home'; ?>
<?php $metaTags = 'tag1 tag2'; ?>
<?php $currentPage = 'index'; ?>
<?php require_once(__DIR__.'/head.php'); ?>
<?php require_once(__DIR__.'/php'); ?>
<body>
    <h1>Index Page, Home has an active class</h1>
    <?php require_once(__DIR__.'/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Then use these variables in the included file:

`head.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo($title); ?></title>
<meta name"description" "<?php echo($metaTags); ?>"><!-- note that this code is wrong -->
<link href="#">
</head>
```

`navbar.php`:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li <?php if ($currentPage === 'Home') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="index">Home</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

In this last part, it's easier to use an array instead of repeating the same code for each line:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php
        // Define each name associated with an URL
        $urls = array(
            'Home' => '/',
            'Page 1' => '/page1',
            // …
        );
        
        foreach ($urls as $name => $url) {
            print '<li '.(($currentPage === $name) ? ' class="active" ': '').
                '><a href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Now you can copy-paste `index.php` as a new file, and add to your navbar, a link will be added on every page.