# Is there a proper method to create Global Navigation menu for websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

ex. Creating one file to inject Navigation menu into a website. 
I see that php is one way to do it, or just making an html frame. What do professionals use nowadays?

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460276/php-include-nav-bar-for-every-page-techniques

Comment: a downvote means the question shows little research and also can be unclear or not useful. BTW I didn't downvote

Comment: well I didnt see any questions similar to this with searches on stackoverflow, and very little on youtube and google searches.

Answer (score 0):

Standard is, to use a [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines).

Many examples are available for PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

The current practice is to build a single page application in which everything is retrieved in a single page load and "pages" are emulated using hash locations. So you switch out main content without having to access the server reload static content like the menu, sidebar and footer.  All of the new Javascript frameworks (Angular, React, etc.) use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As alex in said, use a template engine with partial code. example for ejs template engine

header.ejs

```
<nav class=\"nav\"> 
   <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/\">Home</a> 
   <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/about\">About</a> 
   <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/contact\">Contact</a> 
</nav>
```

footer.ejs

```
<footer class=\"footer\"> 
    <p class=\"text-center\">© 2020 abc media. All rights reserved</p> 
</footer>
```

the main file can contain

```
<%- include('partials/header') %> 
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```