# Can PHP's require be used to require the head and body at the same time?

Tags: php, require, head, document-body

Is it possible to use PHP to include the contents of the `<body>` on one page, and add it to the `<body>` of the other page, while doing the same thing for the header? Or is it just easier / better to use two pages? This is kind of what I'm going for:

**Some Page**

```
<html>
<head>
 - nav.php's header -
 - stuff special to Some Page -
</head>
<body>
 - nav.php's body -
 - content special to Some Page -
</body>
</html>
```

I know the `require` statement can be used to take the whole contents of a file. Is there some sort of "merge" statement to kind of merge the pages together?

Comment: i think include an example will be helpful to understand what you looking for

Comment: @GNassro Is that better? I don't want to add too much.

Comment: you said **(nav.php) that displays a navigation menu on all the pages of the website**, so i think the best way is to replace all of <head> content from nav.php to index.php, maybe this post will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460276/php-include-nav-bar-for-every-page-techniques

Comment: Strictly speaking, `<link>` tags don't need to be in the `<head>` section.

Comment: @GNassro If I'm understanding the link you sent me, it is separating the head and body into separate files. I'm wondering if there is a way around this; like i said in my question "I can always require two separate files, one for the head and one for the body, but this gets tedious as more and more pages are created." Also, replacing the head content in ```index.php``` with the ```nav.php``` header defeats half the point; redoing the CSS on all the pages is one of the things I'm trying to avoid. I'm just asking if this is possible, or if it is just easier to use separate files.

Comment: @kmoser In my testing, putting the ```<link>``` tag in the body wasn't working for me. Also, according to the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element) I found, this is stated: *If the rel attribute is used, the element can only sometimes be used in the body of the page. When used with the itemprop attribute, the element can be used both in the head element and in the body of the page, subject to the constraints of the microdata model.*

Comment: You should put styles into css file, them use class and id on your html tags. Browser will cache the file so it won't ruin performance, even if only a few of your php pages use a particular style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to run into all sorts of security, re-use and maintenance issues if you rely on the inline behaviour of included files in PHP. But if you stick to some simple rules you can avoid these problems:

- Any HTML tag opened by PHP must be closed in the same scope (i.e. function)
- Included files must only contain namespace, constant, function and object definitions or further include/require statements (but using the autoloader is prefereable).

So applying these to your base page above, and observing the established good practice of putting includes/requires at the top of your page....

```
<?php
// always start your page with a PHP block - it makes interfering with the headers
// much less painful

require_once('nav.inc.php');

function local_head_content()
{
  ...
}

function local_body_content()
{
   ...
}
?>
<html>
<head>
 <?php 
   nav_head_content();
   local_head_content(); 
 ?>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
   nav_body_content();
   local_body_content();
</body>
</html>
```

But it would probably be better to invoke local_head_content() / local_body_content() as [callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) from nav content.

(yes it is possible to do what you ask, even without function calls - but it would be a very bad idea which is why I've not explained how to do this).

A more conventional approach to solving the problem of shared content across different files is to use a [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern - instead of the webserver selecting the page specific content, this is done in the PHP code with all URLs pointing to the [same entry script](https://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/).

Comment: Interesting technique to use functions - if I'm understanding you right, the functions are supposed to echo the html where they are ran. One question: how is it a security and maintenance issue to require files? In my case, the point of requiring the nav.php file is so if I want to add something to all the pages / edit the navigation bar, I can just change one file, which seems like the opposite of a maintenance issue.

Comment: That is 2 questions, not one. But both are relating to controlling the sequence in which events occur.

Comment: Er ... not sure how that is two questions ... are you counting the first sentence? Anyway, not sure what you mean. So your saying that using requires / includes causes issues if they aren't put at the top of the document, because the sequence somehow messes up. But how does the sequence mess up? Like are people able to intercept and change the incoming required document, if tags have already been sent to the client, in some special way not normally doable from the inspect panel? Thanks.

Comment: It's a maintenance/security issue to rely on inline code in external files. And depending on how your webserver is configured someone can execute the file out of context by supplying its URL.

Comment: It seems like the second sentence is true no matter if the require is at the top or inside the page, and luckily I already use the htaccess file to make referencing the nav.php page cause a 404 error. I just don't see how inline code is a problem - are you saying it is unpredictable? It seems like it would be an issue even if you use functions to print out the HTML then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including `nav.php` in the `<body>` of `index.php`, `nav.php` should not contain tags like `<html>`, etc. since that will result in a final page which does not conform to the HTML spec.

Using your example, this is the contents of the `index.php` page which will be received by the browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style>
 - styles for index.php -
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<style>
 - Style for navigation menu -
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<nav>
 - Navigation -
</nav>
</body>
</html>

<content>
 - content here -
</content>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, your final page contains multiple `<!DOCTYPE>` tags, multiple `<html>` tags, etc.

**`nav.php` should contain only the tags which you want to be included in that part of the final page.** So your `nav.php` should look more like this:

```html
<nav>
 - Navigation -
</nav>
```

As for your styles in `index.php`, you should have a `<link>` tag which pulls in an external style sheet, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`. All the CSS for all pages would go in `style.css`.

Comment: I know what your saying about the extra tags and stuff, but like in the post I mentioned that they have disappeared. Also, I'm not only trying to include the styles, but links to other things, such as the favicon.ico, and [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/). I'm more just asking: should I be using separate files (one for the header and one for the body) or is there a way to use one file and split it. Just to clarify, the nav.php is both for the navigation menu and for the stuff required on every page.

Comment: @mega12345mega If tags are disappearing, it's likely that the browser is cleaning up the page behind the scenes to be standards compliant. In any case, incorrect tags have no effect at best, and may cause harm (incorrectly rendered page) at worst. As for one `include` vs. multiple, that's really a judgment call. There is no single right or wrong answer.